# What is this connector that allows wires to be pushed in without stripping first?

Tags: connector

I have exhausted my resources on Google trying to find this connector, mainly because I'm not quite sure what to search for. Per the photos, it looks like you can push the wires in and two metal conductors strips the housing.

In addition, how does one go about finding such things online? I have tried reverse image searches, looking through the thousands of Mouser catalogs, and tried every sequence of keywords I could think of.

[image]

[image]

Comment: the form of wire connection is called `insulation displacement connection`

Comment: look for any printed markings on the connector

Comment: @jsotola I found AMP E8 on the side, but surprisingly that didn't help in my searches.

Comment: you googled `amp e8 connector`  and got absolutely no usable results?

Comment: @jsotola For some reason, no..

Comment: Scotchlok was one name used in the UK motor trade...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of connectors can be found at Digi-key in section "[Rectangular Connectors - free hanging](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-connectors-free-hanging-panel-mount/316?k=IDC)". Also known as a variant of IDC. Also known as "Mass Termination Assembly" (MTA) connector. You will need a special [insertion tool/plug](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=408-7907&DocType=SS&DocLang=EN) to make them useful.

[image: Rectangular]

Comment: You guys are fantastic!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The general term is "Insulation Displacement Connector". Sometimes abbreviated to IDC. There are many different types though.

It would help if you could find the manufacturer.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulation-displacement_connector)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are looking for the:
AMP, Inc. 644042-4 4 Position MTA-100 IDC Connector 22AWG .100" PITCH 2.54mm

Using the above as a search key, you will find even eBay listings for this style of connector housing.